# How can I prove the values of convergence for $x^n/n$ without using the Ratio or Root test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

If I'm given $\sum \frac{x^n}{n}$ how can I find which values of x the series converges for?

My gut instinct is that it would be for any values in $-1< x < 1$ because the numerator is an exponential function and the denominator is just n, thus having $|x| < 1$ means the numerator wouldn't go to infinity, but would continue getting smaller as n approaches infinity, thus making the series converge to $0$.

However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to prove that without using the Ratio test, which is required for the problem. Is this possible and what should I be looking at to prove it without that? It's supposed to be have two different sets of values for x to where it's converging absolutely and converging conditionally.

Comment: Is there some reason you're avoiding the ratio test?

Comment: @Randall It's required for this problem, I updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: I am confused by the question. Why do you first say that n must be between -1 and 1 and then say that n goes to infinity and the absolute value of x is less than one?  Did you mix up your n's and x's?

Comment: @EricLippert Oh sorry, yeah, the $-1 < n < 1$ should've been $x$. My bad.

Comment: Also, how does the value of each summand getting smaller make the value of the sum converge *to zero*?  You can't sum positive numbers up to a zero value.

Comment: @EricLippert Wouldn't it eventually get very close to zero because it's being divided by n as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Sure, the summands get arbitrarily close to zero. But by "the series converges" we don't mean that the summands get arbitrarily close to zero; we mean that the *sum* has a finite limit, not necessarily zero. The summands of the series 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 ... get arbitrarily close to zero but the sum converges to 2, not zero. The summands of the series 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4... get arbitrarily close to zero but the sum doesn't converge at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gut instinct is good.  You can just use the comparison test to a geometric sequence,  taking absolute values to show absolute convergence.

If $x \in (-1,1)$, then $|x^n/n|<|x^n|$,  and that's a geometric series which converges, therefore your series converges.  At +1, you have the harmonic series which diverges.  At -1 you have the alternating harmonic series, which converges by the alternating series test.

If $x>1$ or $x<-1$,  then the sequence does not go to 0, so it diverges by the divergence test

Answer (score 1):

We have the following cases:

- If $x=1$, then $\sum x_n/n=\sum 1/n$ is the harmonic series, which is known to diverge.
- If $|x|>1$, then $x^n/n$ diverges (diverging exponential growth divided by linear growth). For a series $\sum a_n$ to converge it is a necessary criterion that $a_n\to 0$. Hence the series $\sum x_n/n$ cannot converge.
- If $x\in[0,1)$, then the sum is monotone and also dominated by $\sum x^n$ which converges to $x/(1-x)$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$ (geometric series). Hence, $\sum x_n/n$ also converges.
- If $x\in[-1,0)$, then $x^n/n$ is an alternating sequence which converges monotonically to zero. [It is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) that series over alternating and vanishing sequences always converge.

So over all, your instinct was right and the sequence converges for $|x|<1$ and diverges for $|x|>1$. Additionally, the sequence converges in *one* of the boundary points of its convergence interval, namely $x=-1$, and diverges in the other one.

---

By the way, here is some *taylor series* magic. Lets differentiate the series term-wise:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n\quad\to\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}.$$

So the derivative seems to be $1/(1-x)$, which implies that $\sum x^n/n$ converges to $-\log(1-x)$ (wherever it converges). However, a rigirous reasoning needs some more thought on taylor series and differentiability.

Comment: at $x=-1$ it's just the alternating harmonic, which converges

Comment: @Alan Yeah, I edited already.